# Large series resistor to protect from shock

Tags: high-voltage, protection, tesla-coil, shock

I built a high voltage generator and want to protect myself against shocks.

Would putting a large series resistor on the powering circuit be sufficient to protect me in those cases:

1. I build a large Marx generator (large DC impulsions), and I put a 10 Mohm resistor on my main 1000V power supply? (should limit to 0.1 mA and not shock, right?)
2. I build a Tesla coil generator (large AC generator), say 50 kHz, and I put a 10 Mohm resistor on my main power supply? (I should be protected thanks to the resistor but also thanks to the high frequency?)

Would those protection allow me to make arcs safely through my body?

Comment: `Also, would those protection allow me to make arcs safely through my body ?` an arc requires thermionic emission of electrons and they would come from your body so no, nothing you can do will ever make this nutty idea safe.

Comment: Arcing with freq greather than 20kHz should be safe considering the body is only sensitive to low freq no?

Comment: Those resistors better be rated for the voltage you use them at. Resistors have voltage ratings just as capacitors do. For any resistor to be effective, you must use it well within its voltage *and* power rating. In safety critical applications - and this is one of them! - you should also make any single failure not impair the safety. Thus you'll always use at minimum two series resistors, specified such that if one fails shorted, the other still provides protection.

Comment: In all cases, remember that electric shocks can cause delayed heart rhythm anomalies, so if you shock yourself hard enough to feel it, you should not just ignore it. Never work on high voltages alone. Always have a second person present with you. That's the basic safety rule, always to be followed. Your life is worth more than some experiment. Never skimp on effective safety measures, and having an assistant present, trained in *safe* response to electric shocks, with a procedure in place for what to do to safely get you help, is essential. Anticipate problems before they occur.

Comment: @JeanMi that may be true but, arcing at high frequencies will burn the skin. Don't miss the bigger picture here.

Comment: If you are not experienced in working with high voltages don't play with it until you are. Note that a Marx generator works with air gaps that eventually short out with a discharge. Even a small resistor could become an air gap and arc across from end to end providing no protection. If you get near certain parts of a Marx generator circuit you may become an air gap too. If you are not experienced but still want to experiment with either circuit type it may be best to first buy a commercially made device (with full documentation) and the proper safety measures already installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Marx generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Marx_Generator.svg) works by charging capacitors in parallel then discharging them in series.  The output voltage and current come directly from the capacitors.  The discharge current is **not** limited when you limit the input current.

From Wikipedia:

[image]

The discharge path is completely made of capacitors and the sparkgaps - the resistors have nothing to with the discharge.

The output current of a Tesla coil should be limited by the input current, but I wouldn't want to count on that to keep me safe.